# How do I slow down an a sprite animation with processing java

Tags: java, animation, processing, sprite

I'm attempting to slow down a sprite animation that I found from this website here: https://processing.org/examples/animatedsprite.html

Here is the class for the animation:

```java
class Animation {
  PImage[] images;
  int imageCount;
  int frame;
  
  Animation(String imagePrefix, int count) {
    imageCount = count;
    images = new PImage[imageCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      // Use nf() to number format 'i' into four digits
      String filename = "images/" + imagePrefix + nf(i, 2) + ".png";
      images[i] = loadImage(filename);
    }
  }

  void display(float xpos, float ypos) {
    frame = (frame+1) % imageCount;
    image(images[frame], xpos, ypos);
  }
  
  int getWidth() {
    return images[0].width;
  }
}
```

From the website showing the animation, it says:

> It would be easy to write a program to display animated GIFs, but would not allow as much control over the display sequence and **rate of display.**

So far, the animation plays at the current frame rate (around 60 FPS), but what if I want to play  it at 5 FPS? Obviously, I can't just slow down the entire framerate, because I want just the animation to slow down, not my entire project/canvas.

I've tried slowing the animation down by doing something like this:

```java
if (frameCount % 10 == 1) {
 //Show image
}
```

But the above approach flashes the image, only showing it every ten frames. **How would I successfully slow down the rate of display of the animation, so that the frames don't appear so quickly?**

Here's what the animation looks like right now:

[image]

And here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sooo close ! :)

You've got the solution pretty much using `frameCount`, just need to separate the frame update from the drawing. You want to update based on the frameCount (every once in a while), but display continuously:

```java
void display(float xpos, float ypos) {
    if(frameCount % 12 == 0){
      frame = (frame+1) % imageCount;
    }
    image(images[frame], xpos, ypos);
}
```

(feel to ajust 12 (60/5) to what suits your project best)

Shameless plug, you can also use the [image-sequence-player](https://github.com/hirschandmann/image-sequence-player) library I wrote which allows you to call `setDelay(1000/5)` to have the image sequence play at 5fps.